# Where to keep the scoresheet

Tags: tournament, scoresheet

Does anybody know if there is a standard "place" to keep the scoresheets of past games? I am currently using a photo album since the size of developed photos is more or less the size of my scoresheet when I fold it once, but I would like something more "professional" (that is, less homespun).

I know that there are [scorebooks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007GPE6N4), but that would mean that I have to write up again all my games. I would like to keep the scoresheets, and if possible for fast review (for preparation purposes).

Comment: Mine also do, after computer analysis I store them in a .pgn database. I'm looking something just for the scoresheets.

Comment: If you have the games in a databse in PGN, what's the use of keeping the scoresheets around?

Comment: Because of the sentimental value and because my coach usually asks for them when analyzing the games.

Comment: I gave up on keeping them. Perhaps some will be kept, but then I will put them in a proper frame. That's how important they should be for me to keep them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cigar box is one way that I've heard of in the past.

Those scorebooks are totally 100% absolutely worth it btw. It's vastly more organized than having hundreds of loose sheets.

Comment: I played a fair number of USCF rated games. I think I am missing 3 or 4 scoresheets - these were from my first tournaments when I didn't have one of the standard spirals.

Comment: I'm convinced by the scorebook then. I'll revise my games and see an evolution (hopefully) when I rewrite them.

Answer (score 5):

I used to keep scoresheets in the past, but it's tedious to keep them. Firstly, you may not recognise the writing that you recorded in hurry during the game. Besides, it is hard to be systematic with them: a single shuffle will make your games jumble up, and it will waste a lot of time.

Therefore, instead of doing it manually, I do it electronically. The main recommendation of mine is chess apps. For me, it's just Droidfish. You can get them on apps stores and it is free. Now comes the fun part. You can input your game by manual, which is playing out moves on your phone in double player mode and save it. You can also play the moves out in programs and get its pgn, then input into your phone using a cable. Either way its good.

Alternatively, chess5.com is a good website to keep your games. And do remember, if you use droidfish, keep a copy of the pgn file of your game in your computer in case your phone breaks.

Have fun

Comment: I use Droidfish's "share" feature to export my PGN's to Google Drive once I've entered them. No problems if something were to happen to my phone.

Answer (score 3):

I've built some software that makes it possible to 'scan' your paper scoresheet into electronic .pgn format just by taking a picture of it with your phone after the game (you have to use a particular format for it to understand).

The website, then keeps an electronic copy of the game on your behalf. Let me know if you are interested in trying it out-> [www.chesschecker.com](http://chesschecker.com)

Comment: That's a good idea, Andy. I have spend several several days digizing my scoresheets once when my laptop hard disk failed. After that incident, I have the habit of backing my database to dropbox once every month.

Comment: Just signed up in your site. I can't digitize the games from tournament scoresheets? Only possible in the format you've suggested in your site? @AndyM

Comment: @ArunJ The website has been updated to use easier to use scoresheets.